# etc/gufw/app-profiles

Tags: ubuntu-mate, gufw

In my etc/gufw folder I have an app-profiles folder which contains many txt files such as "overkill.jahnsonxi" and "blood2.jhansonxi" I'd really appreciate someone explaining what these are. 
I've opened some in PLUMA and they appear to relate to games, none of which I have installed. Here is an example:-

[0verkill]
title=0verkill
description=An ASCII-art 2D deathmatch game
ports=6666
categories=Games;Action;
reference=[http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~brain/0verkill/index.cgi?mainpage 0verkill mainpage]

The second question is any thoughts as to how they arrived in GUFW, which I do have installed and running with the default settings."All out none in"

Finally do I need them?

I've tried unsuccessfully to find an explanation or even a mention of "jhansonxi" and his(?) profiles.
I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on an ASUS F552L (X550LA) laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files belong to the installation of `gufw` and will be used to create firewall rules for applications. This is just for your convenience.

Example:

You have `Blood2` installed and want to play it online. You will need to allow incoming connections on port 6666. You can add the firewall rule in the `Preconfigured`-tab by choosing the application. When you click the `Applications`-button you will see a list of applications. You may filter the list with the `Category`- and `Subcategory`-buttons.

[image]

This is useful as you probably don't know which ports are used by an application, so using preconfigured rules give you the ability to easily add the correct rules for the application you want to use.

So the files in `/etc/gufw/app_profiles` are just a collection of known applications which will be used to quickly create firewall rules for your applications. If you don't add any rules in the described way, the files will not be used, just leave them where they are, they don't harm your system in any way.

Comment: SOLVED. Thank you "mook765" your answer is really appreciated. This is so typical of the support available with Ubuntu, and reinforces my decision to switch. Hal.